# Accessing a samba share from a separate LAN

Tags: samba, port-forwarding, local-area-network

I have 2 LANs at home :

- A main LAN running behind my ISP's modem (acting as a router with an
  IP address of 192.168.0.1, which I'll refer to as router A). Attached
  to this router is a Raspberry Pi at 192.168.0.4.
- A secondary LAN running behind a wireless TP-LINK router, connected
  to my modem (my main LAN) at 192.168.0.10 (so this router's default
  gateway is 192.168.0.10), which I'll refer to as router B. the
  router's IP address on its LAN is 192.168.1.1. Attached to this
  router is a hard drive that I access via a samba share on address
  192.168.1.1.
  Here's an overview of this setup :

`Router A 192.168.0.1
   |
   | - Raspberry Pi
   |
Router B 192.168.0.10 to router A,
   |      192.168.1.1 to clients within
   |
Samba server - 192.168.1.1`

I'm trying to access my samba share from my Raspberry Pi, but since they are in different LANs, the Pi can't see my samba share. I tried forwarding samba ports on router B (ports 137 through 139, and port 445), and accessing the share from the Pi using IP 192.168.0.10 (router B's IP address on the Pi's LAN), but it's not working. When I attach the Pi to router B's LAN (using a wifi dongle), I can access the samba share just fine on IP 192.168.1.1, but since they are far away, I keep losing the connection. How would you suggest I go about doing this, without physically connecting the Pi to router B?

Comment: the netbios resolution doesn't work between two lans, unless you use ip helper to foward the broadcast traffic between the two routers, but i don't think your home routers has that technology.

Comment: I'm not well versed in networking, could you please elaborate ?

Comment: From RPi, what says `traceroute 192.168.1.1` ? I suspect a route is missing on router A to be able to reach router B network. I think  an improved design would be to not have to NAT (nor port forward) when trying to reach router B networks from router A...Also, not sure why router B and Samba share have the same ip (192.168.1.1)...

Comment: Why do I have to set a route when I'm trying to access the share using router B's IP address ? wouldn't the port forwarding mechanism forward requests to samba ports on 192.168.0.10 to the same ports on router B's internal IP ?
Samba share has the same IP because it's a built-in feature in router B to access a hard drive attached to it.

Comment: I should mention that I can't add routes to router A, because it's a modem supplied by my ISP.

Answer (score 2):

You have a **routing** problem.

Consider this: your RPI (192.168.0.x) does know nothing about the existence of another LAN (192.168.1.x). How can you inform it that another LAN exists right next to it? Answer: by using a **route**, which is a very specific piece of information stating how a particular subnet/host can be reached.

In your example, your LAN 192.168.1.x in behind the "router B" host (192.168.0.10). In order to reach the LAN 192.168.1.x, hosts connected to the other LAN (192.168.0.x) had to be know this very same thing. In other words, you had to tell your 192.168.0.x LAN that the other LAN (192.168.1.x) can be seen through router 192.168.0.10.

You can accomplish this using the following Linux routing command: `route add -net 192.168.1.0/24 gw 192.168.0.10`. Theoretically, this command is needed on each host residing on the 192.168.0.x LAN - a somewhat annoying thing to accomplish when you have multiple (maybe tents of) hosts. However, another solution exists: let the various 192.168.0.x hosts know nothing of the other LAN, but inform the main router (router A - 192.168.0.1) that such a network exists. From what I read, however, you can not alter router A's routing table in any mode, so you can only use the first method explained above.

A last, discouraged solution not involving routing modification is the port forwarding method. In this case, you basically tell to router B (192.168.0.10) to setup a "fake" samba listener, and to redirect each samba requests to the internal samba server 192.168.1.1. Why is this discouraged? Because NAT can uselessly increase network complexity, and because it require significant processing by router B - slowing down your connections.

One last thing: doing your test/setup, *always use samba's IP address and not its server name.* This because NETBEUI (which evolved into NETBIOS) was not designed to functions between different LANs, and this affect its name resolving capabilities. So let's keep things simple here: use samba server's IP address to testing connections.

Comment: I tried adding the route to my RPi as per your suggestion, but it still can't see the samba share. Here's a result of the ping before and after adding the route : http://imgur.com/hi2RmHP

Comment: I tried setting up the "fake" samba listener (see forwarded ports on router B here : http://imgur.com/wxeAti2), and accessing the share using IP 192.168.0.10, but it's not working either. What am I doing wrong ?